# Which version of Quake 2 source code do I need to compile to work with version 3.20 map packs?

Tags: c++, windows, quake2

I'm a big fan of `Quake 2` game. Recently I've decided to spend some of my free time for digging into the `Quake 2` src code. There are 2 versions of the full game code `3.19` and `3.21` (including the `game exe` as well as the `game dll`).

As regards to the Q2 Mission Packs the src files for both The Reckoning and Ground Zero are rather of verions 3.20 as the filename suggests (`xatrixsrc320.exe` and `roguesrc320.exe`)

My question is WHICH version of the `game exec` do I have to compile to use with the mission pack dlls? Is it better to use the `3.21` exe together with `3.20` of the xatrix & rogue dlls, or maybe the older `3.19` would be more appropriate?

Comment: Which one did you try so far? Did it work? If not, what specific problem did you encounter that we can help you overcome?

Comment: @DMGregory. Haven't tried any so far. I just have asked about the recommendation. I'll try to use 3.21. Thx.

Comment: "I haven't tried any" means it's too early to ask here. Always *try something* first. If it works when you try it, then you never needed to waste any time asking in the first place. If it doesn't work, the particular *way* it fails to work (error messages, undesired behaviour symptoms) can give you useful information to ask a more detailed question.

Comment: @DMGregory. Ok I've compiled the `3.21 exe` and `3.20 xatrix dll` and when i run `quake2 +set game xatrix` i'm getting oin the game console: "... Dropped frame 21 > 20 ..." and the map/game isn't loading...

Comment: Sounds like that should be part of your question.

Comment: @DMGregory Ok, right but do You have an idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Edit your question first (and un-accept your current answer - or just post a new question), then if users have answers for you, they will post them as Answers below.

Comment: @DMGregory Ok, i cannot delete this question chance it has answers, but i'm posting  a new, more adequate one.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at [the changelog for 3.20 and 3.21](https://archive.org/details/Quake_2_source_code):

> 12-22-2001, for source release under GPL licensing:
>
> - Tweaked linux/Makefile for easier build   added linux/README-3.21-RELEASE
>
> 3.21 Changes:
>
> - Support for GL_ARB_multitexture added.  This supports the new multitexture   extensions and deprecates GL_SGIS_multitexture.
> - Linux OpenGL X11 handling completely rewritten.  Support for XF86DGA Mouse   and fullscreen resolution support added.  Please see the
>   README file for   Linux about the new features of this handling.
>
> 3.20 Changes:
>
> - Fixed a network problem where and oversize packet could cause a client    crash.
> - Fixed the long standing Quake2 bug of where you would occasionally spawn   or teleport and find yourself either looking straight at the
>   ceiling or   down at the floor.
> - Changed it so that the function keys (F1 through F12) now get executed when    depressed during demo playback or attract modes.
>   This allows you to take    screen shots (F12) during demos and other
>   features.  An example of other    features is a fast forward for
>   demos:
>   alias +ff "timedemo 1"
>   alias -ff "timedemo 0"
>   bind f7 +ff   This binding will cause the current demo playing to zip into timedemo mode    while F7 is depressed, effectively acting
>   like a fast forward key.
> - Wrong packaging of 3.19 patch.  The Rogue CD has a 45k pak2 and vwep .md2    files in baseq2/players, but the 3.19 x86 patch we released
>   has a 2.7MB    pak2.  3.20 has a 45k pak2 and the vwep models go in
>   baseq2/players.
> - VWep code has been added to Xatrix dll, new VWep models for the Xatrix    specific weapons (Ion Ripper and Phalanx) have been
>   included.
> - Rogue Linux game library was wrong version and had some unlinked symbols,   this has been corrected.
> - Occasional error of: "D_SCAlloc: bad cache width 16384" in software renderer.   This had to do with surfaces to SURF_FLOWING and were
>   transparent.  This    has been fixed in the refs now so flowing
>   transparent textures now works.
> - [Unix] Net_ErrorToString calls were wrong, was using %i and not %s resulting   in random numbers being printed for error messages.
> - Color shell mixing restored to the same blends as previous versions.  This    was changed in 3.19 for the new color shells the Rogue mission
>   pack    introduced.
> - Fixed a possible server crash in the new "playerlist" command.
> - Fixed a case where a person joining a server could be invisible (left over    setting of SVF_NOCLIENT from previous spectator).
> - Invalid pak files no longer cause a crash and are just ignored
> - Fixed a 3.19 bug where linked models (modelindex2) who's modelindex was    greater than 0x7f causes the wrong model to be drawn (in some
>   cases, the    world would be drawn twice).  This was the cause of many
>   of the "extreme"    frame lag people were seeing in 3.19 on servers
>   using old-style VWep code.
> - Linux:  Complete rewrite of the OpenGL library handling.  This was needed    to cleanly integrate OpenGL extension checking.  Linux now
>   supports    extensions such as multitexture and better dynamic loading
>   of libraries.     It's cleaner now in that you don't have to preload
>   hack stuff to use the    3DFX Miniport rather than libMesa3D.  The
>   Linux version now uses the    gl_driver to specify the 3D library to
>   dynamically load.  For example, to    use the lib3dfxgl.so miniport,
>   one would now use:
>   ./quake2 +set vid_ref gl +set gl_driver lib3dfxgl.so   This change fixes several bugs that were apparant in the older method, such
>   as a segfault occasionally when connecting to a server with a
>   different game    directory.   The vid menu in the Linux version has
>   been changed to reflect the new    options, the current list of
>   supported video drivers are now:  software,    software X11, Mesa 3-D
>   3DFX, 3DFXGL Miniport, OpenGL glX, and Mesa 3-D glX,
> - Railgun shots now go through gibs as well as other players.
> - New server variable, "needpass" that can been seen with server browser   tools such as GameSpy.  This variable indicates whether a
>   password or   spectator password is needed to get onto a server.  Bit
>   0 is password and   bit 1 is spectator password.
> - Quake2 will no longer look for gamex86.dll in the main Quake2 directory.   It will always load out of the game directory first.
> - Players joining a server during an intermission are now moved to the   intermission position.
> - The "logfile" cvar has been extended with the following values:     0 - don't log (default)     1 - overwrite qconsole.log and use buffered
>   writes    2 - overwrite qconsole.log and flush write every line   3 -
>   append to existing qconsole.log and flush write every line
> - Several minor bug fixes to the Rogue mission pack gamex86.dll
> - Linux:  Rebuild of Rogue mission pack shared library to correct some   dynamic symbol errors (is NAN errors).

3.20 seems to include some very desirable fixes, whereas the 3.21 changes should not affect game compatibility.  3.21 therefore appears to be the version you should use.

Comment: Thx for help friend. I'd go with 3.21.